# How to use array .filter() to search key value in JSON array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

If I have an array of objects like so in `playlists.json`

```
"playlists" : [
      {
        "id" : "1",
        "owner_id" : "2",
        "song_ids" : [
          "8",
          "32"
        ]
      },
      {
        "id" : "2",
        "owner_id" : "3",
        "song_ids" : [
          "6",
          "8",
          "11"
        ]
      },
      {
        "id" : "3",
        "owner_id" : "7",
        "song_ids" : [
          "7",
          "12",
          "13",
          "16",
          "2"
        ]
      }
    ]
```

and in Node I read in the file like this:

```
const data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('playlists.json'));
```

I want to write a `.filter()` function that can search by `id` and mutate the result into a new array thereby removing the entry tested for.

Of course we can access the index like this: `playlists[0].id);`

How would write the `.filter()` to test for a certain `id` i.e. generate a new array with value removed? (mutate) I wrote some code below but it is wrong and noob.

```
const someId = "2"
const result = playlists.filter(playlist => playlist.id !== someId)
```

New array of `result` would contain:

```
"playlists" : [
      {
        "id" : "1",
        "owner_id" : "2",
        "song_ids" : [
          "8",
          "32"
        ]
      },
      {
        "id" : "3",
        "owner_id" : "7",
        "song_ids" : [
          "7",
          "12",
          "13",
          "16",
          "2"
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Comment: The `.filter()` code that you showed looks correct. What isn't working correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used filter fine, however, you have select the key from your json object.
Below is an example.

```
 const jsonFile = {
        "playlists" : [
              {
                "id" : "1",
                "owner_id" : "2",
                "song_ids" : [
                  "8",
                  "32"
                ]
              },
              {
                "id" : "2",
                "owner_id" : "3",
                "song_ids" : [
                  "6",
                  "8",
                  "11"
                ]
              },
              {
                "id" : "3",
                "owner_id" : "7",
                "song_ids" : [
                  "7",
                  "12",
                  "13",
                  "16",
                  "2"
                ]
              }
            ]
        }
        const someId = 2
        const result = jsonFile.playlists.filter(playlist => playlist.id !== someId)
        console.log(result)
```

Comment: Excellent Arky.  I arrived at this as well.  I answered my own question, but I will wait a few minutes and give you the green checkbox for answer.  Thanks!

Comment: It would still need to be `const someId = "2"` or `!=` for the equality check to work correctly

Comment: Yup, you're right Nick. Rachel included that in her question, and its included at the very bottom of this code example. That's why I didn't explicitly state it in the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

After some inspection. I needed to used the parent object reference with playlists to achieve the proper result like so:

```
const someId = "2";
const result = data.playlists.filter(playlist => playlist.id !== someId)
console.log(result);
```